# "subscript out of bounds" for matchTab in epicalc package in R

Tags: r

As title, I have collected data for 1:6 matched case-control study and I am trying to analyze the data using `matchTab`, but it gives me error "subscript out of bounds", I wonder if anyone here has met anything similar before. What does it mean? Some issue about my dataset? As I have tried the manual, I can get the result using the dataset used in the manual.

Thanks.

Comment: A reproducible example would be nice/essential.

Answer (score 2):

That error often arises from matrix subsetting beyond the dimensions of the object. Try this for example:

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
mat[,4]
```

with the last line yielding

```
> mat[,4]
Error: subscript out of bounds
```

This sometimes happens in code because the programmer forgot that `[` drops empty dimensions - I've done this myself many times, forgetting the 1 column matrix case! I'm not saying this is the problem here, but is one common cause of it in R code.

As you haven't provided a reproducible example and I am unfamiliar with the package you mention, I can't diagnose the problem further. It could be a bug in their package or a problem with how you have supplied, or understood you needed to supply, data to the function.

First thing I would do is re-read the man page for the function. Confirm you have the arguments supplied correctly. If that doesn't help, rerun to generate the error and then call `traceback()` to see exactly in what function the error is being raised. To debug further, try

```
options(error = recover)
```

then rerun your code. This will drop you into the debugger so you can go into the frame where the error occurred and see what all the objects were like, how they were sized etc. and why the error was being raised.

If you are not up to debugging this yourself, you might need to contact the maintainers, or provide a reproducible example...